# How to view which IRP's handled by mini filter driver?

Tags: filesystems, driver, minifilter, sysinternals, irp

We register mini file system filter driver with fltmgr i.e filter manager in windows,and we register IRP for callbacks (preoperation and postoperation callbacks) in that.
As if we know its up-to us to for which IRP we want callback from filter manager.
*So my question is how I can find out the any third party filter driver handling which IRP and which IRP its not handling?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a third party filter registers for an IRP it can do nothing just pass-thru the IRP, So cannot know it does something with IRP. Again Filter driver should not have dependency on a third party filter driver.

But can check tools like [IRP tracker](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=199) and [fltmc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried the IRP tracker in that we can see the IRP's of any created device object in filter driver e.x CDO in driver but not of filter driver. In case of fltmc I tried many different things but I think i need to explore more on that.